# How to refresh user control on the button click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am showing user control on the popup. Like as:

```
 xmlns:TimelogCustomControl="clr-namespace:TechTouch.CustomControl"
```

And showing in the grid control like as:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <TimelogCustomControl:OnDutyPopUp  Value="{Binding TimeLogModel.HeaderDutyText,Mode=TwoWay}"   VerticalAlignment="Top"></TimelogCustomControl:OnDutyPopUp>
                                        </Grid>
```

And now i want to refresh data of this user control on the button click for that We will show updated functionality on this page. How to fix this problem? If possible please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

**If following MVVM**

Add a button in view, bind a command to it and fire property changed for 
TimeLogModel in command handler.

**if not.**

In click handler raise property changed for TimeLogModel.

Comment: Correction - button in view not viewmidel